# Concatenate 1D and 2D arrays as per index position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to concatenate a 1D into a 2D array. I'd like to avoid doing a loop as it's very computer intensive if my array lengths are greater than 1000.

I have tried vstack, stack and concatenate with no success.

```
import numpy as np

array_a = np.array([1,2,3])

array_b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32]])
```

The expected output should be

`array([[1, 10, 11, 12], [2, 20, 21, 22], [3, 30, 31, 32]])`

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Mykola showed the right way to do this, but I suspect you need a little help in understanding why.  You tried several things without telling us what was wrong.

```
In [241]: array_a = np.array([1,2,3]) 
     ...: array_b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32]])
```

`vstack` runs:

```
In [242]: np.vstack((array_a, array_b))                                         
Out[242]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [20, 21, 22],
       [30, 31, 32]])
```

But the result is a **vertical** join, by rows, not columns. The `v` in `vstack` is supposed to remind us of that.

`stack` tries to join the arrays on a **new** axis, and requires that all input array have a matching shape:

```
In [243]: np.stack((array_a, array_b))                                          
...
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

I suspect you tried this at random, without really reading the docs.

Both of these use `concatenate`, which is the basic joiner.  But it's picky about dimensions:

```
In [244]: np.concatenate((array_a, array_b))                                    
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

You clearly realized that the number of dimensions didn't match.

You want to make a (3,4) array.  One is (3,3), the other needs to be (3,1).  And join axis needs to be 1

```
In [247]: np.concatenate((array_a[:,None], array_b), axis=1)                    
Out[247]: 
array([[ 1, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 2, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 3, 30, 31, 32]])
```

If we made a (1,3) array, and tried to join on the default 0 axis, we get the same thing as the `vstack`.  In fact that's what `vstack` does:

```
In [248]: np.concatenate((array_a[None,:], array_b))                            
Out[248]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [20, 21, 22],
       [30, 31, 32]])
```

Another function is:

```
In [249]: np.column_stack((array_a, array_b))                                   
Out[249]: 
array([[ 1, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 2, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 3, 30, 31, 32]])
```

This does the same thing as [247].

Functions like `vstack` and `column_stack` are handy, but in long run it's better to understand how to use `concatenate` itself.

Comment: Thank you so much @hpaulj! This is making far much more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You want [insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np

array_a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

array_b = np.array([[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32]])

result = np.insert(array_b, 0, array_a, axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1 10 11 12]
 [ 2 20 21 22]
 [ 3 30 31 32]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel! I'll do a timeit on all these methods given and reply with a performance review. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can `reshape()` the first array and then `concatenate()` both arrays:

```
np.concatenate([array_a.reshape(3, -1), array_b], axis=1)
```